# What exactly is a Goa'uld Queen?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In Season 6's *Cure*, we see Egeria, a Goa'uld queen that is creating symbiotes.

[image: Egeria, Goa'uld Queen]

However in Season 1's *Hathor*, we also see the eponymous Goa'uld queen creating symbiotes.

[image: Hathor, Goa'uld Queen]

How can both of these be Goa'uld queens? One of them is a non-human while one of them is apparently a typical Goa'uld inhabiting a human (which lacks any obvious symbiote-creating organs). One might assume that Egeria is a symbiote inhabiting some non-human animal, but Teal'c recognizes it immediately as a Goa'uld queen, suggesting that this animal *is* a Goa'uld queen, rather than a species inhabited by one.

I suppose I just need some clarification. What exactly is a Goa'uld queen? How can both Egeria and Hathor be queens? If they are both symbiotes, why are they different than other Goa'uld?

Comment: "(which lacks any obvious symbiote-creating organs)" suppose the human reproductive organs aren't good enough - I'd call them obvious, but I don't know, you seem to have exclusive information here - the monster is still physically inside that person with all its obvious organs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We never see Hathor "in the flesh" on screen, however we know that queens are just as capable of inhabiting a host as a normal Goa'uld. Egeria was able to do the same to [Kelmaa](http://www.gateworld.net/wiki/Kelmaa).

The main difference between the queens and normal Goa'uld is that queens can spawn new symbiotes (we watch Hathor do this). [Queens can also control the genetics of their offspring](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Goa%27uld_queen)

> While the development of new symbiotes usually involves passing on the Goa'uld genetic memory to its offspring, the queen may choose not to do so -- rendering the symbiotes "blank slates" that are more susceptible to command and domination, rather than thirsting for power and worship of their own. (SG1: "Evolution, Part 2")
>
> When a queen begins to create symbiotes it grows a large sac which contains the young until they are ready for birth. The queen can detach from the sac to enter a host if desired. (SG1: "Cure")

Comment: I think this is really the best answer that we will be able to get in this case. The show never really goes into detail. Towards offspring we see them born in Hathor's bathtub, the pools of Egeria's offspring, and then I think the only other time we really see them is in the giant fishbowl from the episode the steal a symbiote for the female jaffa. Regarding Hathor however it is possible that as a queen she was implanted with tech that allowed her to conceive in such a fashion, given that Apophis and Amaunet had a normal child together though bolstered by the fact it was Harcesis.